# Send data from activity to fragment using Tab Layout with Swipeable Views in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, bundle

I created a Tab Layout with Swipeable Views using this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/). I'm trying to pass a string from Activity to Fragment. I read about [fragment communication](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) and couple other topics on stackoverflow but still i get null pointer exception. Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_EMAIL = 1;
    String password, email;

    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                        FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Głowna").setTag("main").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Rachunki").setTag("bills").setTabListener(tabListener));

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("email", "emasiofnasdbjk");
        EnterExitFragment enterExitFragment = new EnterExitFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.pager, enterExitFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

TabsPagerAdapter.java

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return new EnterExitFragment();
            case 1:
                return new BillsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

EnterExitFragment.java

```
public class EnterExitFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView tvFloor1, tvFloor2, tvEmail;
    Button btnSend;
    Integer floorId, segmentId, spaceId, ticketId;
    String floorName, segmentName, spaceName;
    String email;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_enter_exit, container, false);

        tvEmail = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textEmail));
        tvFloor1 = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textFloor1));
        tvFloor2 = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textFloor2));
        new FloorFreeSpaces(EnterExitFragment.this).execute();

        btnSend = ((Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSend));
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Floor(EnterExitFragment.this).execute();
                email = getArguments().getString("email"); //line 55
                tvEmail.setText(email);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

activity_enter_exit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textFloor1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textFloor2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="354dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:id="@+id/textEmail"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.carpark.EnterExitFragment$1.onClick(EnterExitFragment.java:55)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17722)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone solution for my problem? :)

Comment: Please comment the line 55 of `EnterExitFragment.java` file.

Comment: If I comment line 55 it'll work but I won't get string from `MainActiviti.java`.

Comment: Pardon my illiteracy, I meant put a comment after that line so we can know which one is line 55 :D

Comment: I commented it. Maybe way that I try to sent string from activity to fragment is wrong.

Comment: I do not see that you set bundle to your fragment?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I am trying the same tutorial and I am trying to pass data from the mainactivity to the fragments too, but unable to. @cris135

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My suggestion is to make the following constructor which takes `Bundle` object as an argument:

```
public EnterExitFragment(Bundle bundle) {
    super();
    setArguments(bundle);
}
```

and call that constructor with `bundle` object as the argument instead of the default one in your program. That way you're sure to add the bundle before you attach it to your Activity.

Additionally, if that doesn't work, add a `Bundle` attribute to your EEF class, initialize it within your constructor and refer to it rather than `getArguments()` method:

```
public class EnterExitFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView tvFloor1, tvFloor2, tvEmail;
    Button btnSend;
    Integer floorId, segmentId, spaceId, ticketId;
    String floorName, segmentName, spaceName;
    String email;
    Bundle args;

    public EnterExitFragment(Bundle bundle) {
        super();
        args = bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_enter_exit, container, false);

        tvEmail = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textEmail));
        tvFloor1 = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textFloor1));
        tvFloor2 = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textFloor2));
        new FloorFreeSpaces(EnterExitFragment.this).execute();

        btnSend = ((Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSend));
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Floor(EnterExitFragment.this).execute();
                email = args.getString("email"); //line 55
                tvEmail.setText(email);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: After couple changes every start app on smart-phone I've forgotten about this line, buy it still did't change error it's still null pointer on line 55.

Comment: The LogCat is exactly the same as the one you've posted?

Comment: Yeah, It's the same. After creating tabs like i did, is there any other way to communicate between activity and fragment? Maybe first parameter of replace methof should be different? `transaction.replace(R.id.pager, enterExitFragment);`

Comment: Nah that's OK. The problem may be that you're replacing the containerView rather than attaching/adding the fragment to the activity. However, you can actually add `Bundle` attribute to your `EnterExitFragment` and initialize it with the `bundle` variable from your MainActivity within your EEF constructor. Then refer to it rather than `getArguments()` method. That would work for sure

Comment: But how add `Bundle` attribute to `case 0` in `TabsPagerAdapter.java` ?

Comment: I've created a default constructor in `EnterExitFragment` and change code like You wrote but it still show same error in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that you set your argument to fragment. If you did, but you forgotten to write please inform me...

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("email", "emasiofnasdbjk");
EnterExitFragment enterExitFragment = new EnterExitFragment();
enterExitFragment.setArguments(bundle); // This line is needed...
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.pager, enterExitFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I added this line after NitroNbg saw i forgotten but it don't change error. I wrote about it undermentioned comments.

Comment: Can you try to get email before onClick event, just to ensure if getArgumetns comes to fragment as null, or it comes to onClick as null?