# Android (Java) - Constantly Passing Updated/Live Variable from Activity To Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have a MainActivity.java that uses a BroadcastReceiver to constantly (like every other 2 seconds) detect signals it receives from other external devices. Then this MainActivity is live and keeps detecting signals, it constantly counts how many signals it receives then stores in a variable (varA). Thereafter, I need to display how many signals (varA) has been received in a SignalFragment.java (using fragment as I need the tab/pager, using onCreateView), and the display in the SignalFragment should be live and be updated and displayed in a textview whenever the BroadcastReceiver detect signals (whenever varA changes/updated).

However, I am unable to keep updating the SignalFragment constantly even when I use GlobalState variables. How do you keep updating the textview in the SignalFragment/or keep passing the variable from MainActivity to SignalFragment? How to do this?

Comment: Can't you just have a method in SignalFragment that can be called to update a textView?
The parent activity can just call it whenever it's needed to update.
What's the challenge?
Show code if need more help.

Comment: @uDevel, i tried having a method in SignalFragment, but it doesn't work. 

 public void setNoOfDevices(int noOfDevices) {
  textview.setText(Integer.toString(noOfDevices));
 }

then at my MainActivity, I called 
SignalFragment sf = new SignalFragment();
sf.setNoOfDevices(value);

But it does not show.

Comment: You didn't create a new fragment to call the method, did you?  You should get existing fragment, then call its method, right?

Comment: Oh crap. How do I get the existing fragment? ><

Comment: I put it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event bus like [`Otto`](http://square.github.io/otto/) to publish to your `Fragment` every time you need to update it. Actually, you can push your updates directly from your `BroadcastReceiver` to the `Fragment`.

Comment: How do I push the updates directly from BroadcastReceiver to the Fragment?

Comment: Is there any other ways besides using Otto?

Comment: Yes, but in my opinion they will be more difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you created the instance of SignalFragment in the first place.
You can either call the instance, or find the instance from the fragment manager.

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_SIGNAL_FRAGMENT);
    if(fragment != null)
    {
        ((SignalFragment) fragment).setNoOfDevices(some value);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, what is findFragmentByTag(TAG_SIGNAL_FRAGMENT)?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)

It sounds like you are not sure how you created the fragment.  You might need to show more code on how you created it.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! But I the problem have now is different. I am using this example from androidhive, http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/, and now I want the fragments to share what the broadcastreceiver receives. But I have no idea to put the broadcastreceiver at the tabs adapter? or the mainactivity? Then from there, I register the fragments and make them share the data from the broadcastreceiver? Thanks a lot for your help!! Urgently need this for a project.

Comment: I am now facing the same exact issue as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733810/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-using-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-in-and 
Any advice please? :(